# Suppose I have this loop in Django...how do I display this?

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, templates

```
{% for p in profiles %}
<div class="result">
    {{ p.first_name }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Suppose I have 1000 of these, in a huge list. 
How would I make this code appear every 15 times?

```
<div class="menu">abc</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [forloop.counter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable with [divisbleby](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter.

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisbleby:"15" %}
    <div class="menu">abc</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `forloop.counter` value with a `divisibleby` filter in an `if` condition. See the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins)